# How to find out within a Capybara spec whether JS is active?

Tags: javascript, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Is there a way to detect within an Rspec example whether JavaScript is currently active?

I have a helper function that needs to react differently depending on JavaScript available or not.

```
module Autocomplete
  def select_from_autocomplete(label, id, js = false)
    fill_in "#{id}_filter", with: label # Open autocomplete and filter
    find('label', text: label, visible: js).click    # Capybara's click() doesn't work because the input is visually hidden! And we have to use visible = false because when JS is off, the elements wouldn't be found.
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Autocomplete, type: :feature
end
```

Currently I pass the flag manually (`js = true`), but I would like to detect this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If the visibility of the element changes based whether JS is active or not, can't you just base this on the visibility of the element?

```
if (find(:label, label, visible: :all).visible? )
  ... # do whatever when the element is visible
else
  ... # do otherwise when not visible
end
```

Comment: Nice workaround! I will take a look at it.